# Android async class returns null

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, null

I'm trying to fix this code:

```
public class Async_Test extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private String Response;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    String tmp = "something";
    return tmp;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Response = result;
}

public String getResponse()
{
    return this.Response;
}

}
```

The problem is the following: The getResponse() method is always null.

The execution code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
               try{
                Async_Test t = new Async_Test();
                t.execute("");
                showMainText("res: "+t.getResponse());              
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
                showMainText(e.toString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An async task is asynchronous. More precisely, here is what's going on when you call the `execute()` method :

- a new thread is created.
- the `doInBackground(...)` is executed on this new thread
- when `doInBackground(...)` terminate : `onPostExecute` is executed on the main thread.

Therefore, when you call `showMainText("res: "+t.getResponse());` (it's in the main thread): the `onPostExecute` didn't run yet and `Response` is still null.

To see the effect of AsyncTask: you can put a breakpoint on line :

`showMainText("res: "+t.getResponse());`

and you will see that the displayed text will be "something" (due to the breakpoint : the AsyncTask will have time to be executed.)

To get the result you expect : move the line `showMainText("res: "+t.getResponse());` in the `onPostExecute`

Comment: Yes, it works, but the correct way to fix your problem is to put the code that must be executed after the AsyncTask in the onPostExecute (see last line of my post).